# sublime autocompletion file

Tags: auto-completion, sublime-text

I am just starting to get to grips with sublime and latex. I am trying to get the autocompletion file and autocompletion settings finetuned.

I have the file mylatex.sublime-completion

```
{
        "scope": "text.tex.latex",

        "completions":
        [
                { "trigger": "\\subsection", "contents": "\\subsection{$1}"}
        ]
}
```

and in settings I have

```
"auto_complete_selector": "source, text"
```

the problem i am having is that when I type, I get something like
[image: sublime completion dropdown]

The problem I have with this is that there are a load of entries that I am not interested in. Some of them are from the document itself.
I would like to limit the completions to my personal snippets and completion file.